# Google Compute Engine CentOS Web Panel

Tags: google-compute-engine, centos-web-panel

I have created a `CentOS` **Web Panel** on `Google Compute Engine`.

At the end of the setup is says my `username` is `root` and `password` is 'ssh root server password'. The `google compute engine` doesn't use `ssh` passwords so how am I supposed to log in to the `CentOS` **Web Panel** ?

Comment: You can reset the password for a user by running this command $ sudo passwd USERNAME.

Answer (score 2):

Not only Google Compute Engine, all the Cloud Instances Compute use SSH key pair to login to the VPS/Server.
In this case, after you finished setting up your Centos Web Panel,reboot ther server and login to your SSH (same as you did previously, using your key pair) and then set the password for your root user by this command and submit your new password:

**sudo passwd**

Reboot your server:  **reboot**

Now you can login to your CWP : http://your_ip:2030/

Answer (score 0):

In your case, i will suggest you to set the password for root and then use that new root password for your `CentOS` Web Panel.

When i installed `WebMin on **Google Compute Centos**, then i also set the first time root password and used it for`WebMin` login.

Preparing...

```
           ########################################### [100%]
```

Operating system is CentOS Linux
   1:webmin

```
           ########################################### [100%]
```

`Webmin` install complete. You can now login to https://mymachineIP:10000/
as root with your root password.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old question but posting this so any newcomer can make use of it. 
This is with my experience on that.

First make sure what is your encryption algorithm is.

Be sure to get root access with `sudo -s` .
use `authconfig --test` to check which is the encryption algorithm.  If you get "password hashing algorithm is descrypt" then you have to set is first.
use `authconfig --passalgo=ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM --update`.

Where **ENCRYPTION ALGORITHM** may be SHA-512, SHA-256, MD-5.

After that you create a new password by `passwd` command.
Enter your password and press enter. Your password will not be shown in terminal.
then re-enter the password press enter.

Then go to login page then enter your newly created password as the password.

for further reference - http://forum.centos-webpanel.com/centos-webpanel/how-to-fix-encryption-error-on-login/